# Are all deadlocks caused by a bad query

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

"Transaction (Process ID 63) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

Could this deadlock be caused by something that stored proc uses like SQL mail?  Or is it always caused my something like two applications accessing the same table at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two tables accessing the same table at the same time happens all the time in an application. Generally that won't cause a deadlock. A deadlock typically happens when you have say process 'A' attempting to update Table 1 and then Table 2 and then Table 3, and you have process 'B' attempting to update Table 3, then Table 2, and then Table 1. Process 'A' will have a resource locked that process 'B' needs and process 'B' has a resource process 'A' needs. SQL Server detects this as a deadlock and rolls one of the processes back, as a failed transaction.

The bottom line is that you have two processes attempting to update the same tables at the same time, but not in the same order. This will often lead to deadlocks.

One easy way to handle this in your application is to handle the failed transaction and simply re-execute the transaction. It will almost always execute successfully. A better solution is to make sure your processes are updating tables in the same order, as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Missing Indexes is another common cause of deadlocks. If a select query can get the info it needs from an index instead of the base table, then it won't be blocked by any updates/inserts on the table itself.

To find out for sure, use the SQL profiler to trace for "Deadlock Graph" events, which will show you the detail of the deadlock itself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213030%28SQL.80%29.aspx), I don't think SQL Mail itself would *directly* be the culprit. I say "directly" because I don't know what you're doing with it. However, I *assume* SQL Mail is probably slow compared to the rest of your SQL ops, so if you're doing a lot with that, it could indirectly create a bottleneck that leads to a deadlock if you're holding onto tables while sending off the SQL Mail.

It's hard to recommend a specific strategy without having too many specifics about what you're doing. The short of it is that you should consider whether there's a way to break your dependence on holding onto the table while you're doing this such as using NOLOCK, using a temp table or non-temp "holding" table or just refactoring the SP that is doing the call.